# parsing Json array and using it c#

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem trying to deserialize this json array and trying to use the variables.
here is the json array that I'm trying to use

```
 [ {
 "Room": [   
  {     
    "ID": 347,   
    "Name": "Beach Villas (68 SQM)",   
    "Description": "Nestled amidst the vegetation along the pristine white beach, the elegantly designed Beach Villas feature natural wood & stone flooring, open-air bathroom, private outdoor setting with direct access to the beach. ",   
         "FileImageUrl": "http://url.com?filedataid=160"
  }   
],   
   "RoomFacility": [   
  {   
    "Facility": "Air conditioning"   
  },  
  {
    "Facility": "Coffee/tea/espresso making facilities"   
  },   
  {   
    "Facility": "Private Deck"   
  },   
  {
    "Facility": "Mini Bar"   
  },
  {
    "Facility": "Internet Access"
  },
  {
    "Facility": "Ceiling fan"   
  },   
  {
    "Facility": "Complimentary internet access"    
  },   
  {
    "Facility": "CD/DVD player with home theater system and satellite TV"   
  },   
  {
    "Facility": "Outdoor Bathroom and Jacuzzi Bathtub"   
  },   
  {    
    "Facility": "Safety Box"    
  }     
]  }]
```

c# code to retreive parse JSON arry

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    string text;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(text);

    string roomID = stuff[0]["Room"]["ID"]; 
    ///this line gives me error
```

from this I'm trying to retrive values using the dynamic variable.. 
I tried something like the last line

ERROR

Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "ID". Array position index expected.
any help would be appreciated?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Adding your incorrect C# code would really help here.

Comment: HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);     
httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;   
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";    

var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();   

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
   text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

//till here ok   
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(text);


JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(stuff);   
//here I'm getting error
var array = new JArray(jObject["Room"].Values());

Comment: var array = new JArray(jObject["Room"].Values());

Comment: Do you mind adding that to your question? It's a bit hard to read down here.

Comment: what I want to achieve here is store all the Room details and Room facility into some the user friendly item. above code is for one room, but there can be all the rooms too, which makes it complex.

Comment: sorry abt that. Im newbie to stackoverflow

Comment: No problem. You mentioned an error. Did you noticed the missing semi-colon?

Comment: no, thats just stupid, but that's not the error I'm ggetting       ERROR :: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "ID". Array position index expected

Comment: Could you add the error to your question?

Comment: could you suggest me any other way to iterate through the json array. I think this may not be the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question mentions a possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820198/accessed-jarray-values-with-invalid-key-value-fields-array-position-index-ex)

Change

```
string roomID = stuff[0]["Room"]["ID"];
```

With

```
string roomID = stuff[0]["Room"][0]["ID"];
```

Comment: but could you tell me how to iterate throught Room and RoomFacility objects in case Json array is more lengthy

Comment: @user3363268 I'm going to let you in on a secret. I've never retrieved a json array in C# before. All I did was google the error.

Comment: @user3363268 This has a possible way to iterate through the Json array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132288/iterating-over-json-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Oh! Even I did google search, I guess I'm not at all good with keywords.. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

stuff[0]["Room"] is an array, tray this line:

```
string roomID = stuff[0]["Room"][0]["ID"];
```

Comment: could you suggest me how to iterate throught both the objects in case the total count of 'stuff' object is 6

Comment: okay, In this case I've two objects of Room and RoomFacilty which is wrapped with outer Obejct. so its not very straight forward as the link you had send. Could you suggest me some tips and trick when dealing with complex json array

Comment: If you have a .length property in the array, you can iterate through each list. And i think that you can use foreach() too.

Comment: I suggest you to use Linq in order to work with that kind of arrays.

Comment: thanks @Rangar. there is a length property. Can you send me some tips on how to work linq with json array

Comment: In this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332103/query-an-object-array-using-linq) you can find some tips.