# Deserializing JSON Data with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I am having trouble working with an API, first time I've worked with one. I've managed to use GET to read the data I need and that part is working perfectly, now I need to deserialize the JSON data I am getting back, and I am using Newtonsoft's JSON .NET library. The problem seems to come when I deserialize the data as its exploding and the debugger isn't being helpful. I tried a few suggestions online but no go, so if someone can enlighten me it'd be appreciated. This is the code:

```
 string url = "";
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

 string responseData = readStream.ReadToEnd();

 var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseData);
 var id = results["id"].Value;
 // var name = results.Name;
```

When I run it the debugger throws the following exception at the last line of code:

> {"Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: \"id\". Array position index expected."}

I am fairly sure that ID exists in the data I am getting back.

Json data I am getting back from Smarty Streets:

```
 [
{
    "id": 0,
    "candidate_index": 0,
    "delivery_line_1": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
    "last_line": "Mountain View CA 94043-1351",
    "delivery_point_barcode": "940431351000",
    "components": {
        "primary_number": "1600",
        "street_name": "Amphitheatre",
        "street_suffix": "Pkwy",
        "city_name": "Mountain View",
        "state_abbreviation": "CA",
        "zipcode": "94043",
        "plus4_code": "1351",
        "delivery_point": "00",
        "delivery_point_check_digit": "0"
    },
   ]
```

Comment: Seems lke your response is JArray not JObject. Try `JArray results = JArray.Parse(responseData)`.

Comment: Can you show a json result?

Comment: If you have the JSON and it's always the same format it's usually easier to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) to create the .NET classes and deserialize directly into classes.

Comment: It is indeed JArray. Use `results[0]["id"]`

Comment: Hi LB! Your answer didn't work. webnett I posted the JSON. Craig... will look into that, thanks.

Comment: @LordRelix Of course it should work. Your json is JArray.

Comment: Hmm, will try that then LB. I messed up the suggestion you gave me, will try again

Comment: LB... that did it :D! Please post your answer so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is an array not a single object. So You should use

```
JArray results = JArray.Parse(responseData)
```

to parse the result (like `results[0]["id"]`). If you go the dynamic way then

```
dynamic results = JArray.Parse(responseData)
```

Now, you can use it like `results[0].id`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to "Paste JSON as classes" so it can be deserialised quick and easy.

1. Simply copy your entire JSON
2. In VS: Click Edit > Paste Special >
   Paste JSON as classes

Here is a better explanation n piccas...
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/

Answer (score 0):

Your result appears to be an array of objects, not an array itself.   Try setting `id` to `results["id"][0].Value` and see if you get something.

See this:  [Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "fields". Array position index expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820198/accessed-jarray-values-with-invalid-key-value-fields-array-position-index-ex)

Comment: Tried this, no go. I actually thought this would do it. Error nit gave me: {"Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: \"id\". Array position index expected."}

Comment: I had written it backwards, sorry.    Should have been results[0]["id"], not how I had done it.